# Batch insert in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Hi I am quite new to cpdeignoter I just wanted to ask if I am doing the insert batch in ci right because it seemed not to work here is my controller

```
                    foreach($dat as $key => $val){
                    $data[] = array('ModelNumber' => $_POST['txt_model_num'][$key],
                        'Access' => $_POST['txt_accessories'][$key],
                        'SerialNumber' => $_POST['txt_snum'][$key],
                        'Charges' => $_POST['txt_charges'][$key],
                        'OtherRemarks' => $_POST['txt_rem'][$key],
                        'RequirementID' => $id1);
                }

                $cmd3 = $this->Software_model->add_type($data);

                if($cmd3){

                    foreach($sql->result_array() as $row){
                        $id2 = $row['ID'];
                    }

                    $data2s = array();

                    foreach($dat as $key => $val){
                        $data2s[] = array('EquipmentName' => $_POST['txt_equipb'][$key],
                                    'EquipmentType' => $_POST['txt_equiptype'][$key],
                                    'RequirementID' => $id2);
                    }

                    $cmd2 = $this->Software_model->add_equip($data2s);
```

and this is the model

```
    public function add_type($data)
{
    return $this->db->insert_batch('jobtype', $data);
}
public function add_equip($data2s)
{
    return $this->db->insert_batch('equipment', $data2s);
}
```

and the way I duplicate the textboxes in the views is like this

```
function second function(){
    var etype = document.createElement('input');
    etype.type = 'text';
    etype.setAttribute("name", "txt_equiptype[]");
    etype.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
    etype.setAttribute("id", "etype");
    etype.setAttribute("placeholder", "Enter Equipment Type");
    document.getElementById('third').appendChild(etype);
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You may need to change `$this->Software_model` to lowercase: `$this->software_model`

Comment: Also for security reasons use CI syntax instead of PHP `$_POST`: `$this->input->post('txt_accessories'); `...

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will help you :**

Try out this alternate method :

```
foreach($dat as $key => $val)
{

    $data[$key]['ModelNumber'] = $_POST['txt_model_num'][$key];
    $data[$key]['Access'] = $_POST['txt_accessories'][$key];
    $data[$key]['SerialNumber'] = $_POST['txt_snum'][$key];
    $data[$key]['Charges'] = $_POST['txt_charges'][$key];
    $data[$key]['OtherRemarks'] = $_POST['txt_rem'][$key];
    $data[$key]['RequirementID'] = $id1;
}
/* Note : remove auto increment primary key from above array if you are including*/
```

user it for both the `foreach`

Comment: only the first data that is inputed is being inserted in the db